# How to add list view on application page of appweb in SharePoint Autohosted app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, list-view, autohosted

I am creating SharePoint 2013 autohosted app. In that I want to add created list to my app's application page.

How can I add list view to my app's application page?
Thank you in advance...!

Answer (score 1):

> You can add a list view that displays the contents of the custom list
>   that you created by adding the `WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart`.

Example:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
ID="full" Title="loc:full" >
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart2" 
runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/TestCustomList" IsIncluded="True" 
NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="TestCustomList" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" 
Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x"> 
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Replace `ListUrl="Lists/TestCustomList"` with the Url of your list. and `Title` with the title of your list.
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

Comment: Hey Nadeem, are you sure it will work with auto-hosted app :)

Comment: I haven't worked on autohosted apps. But it does definitely work on app pages of SharePoint hosted and Provider hosted apps.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in autohosted app? I have tried it before but it was not working.

Comment: @RahulGokani I am not sure about auto hosted apps. I haven't worked on them.

Comment: Ohk.... If you find any thing, answers are always welcome...